# First item of dropdownlist item non selectable asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to make first item of ***dropdownlist*** non selectable following is my code.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="IssueList" runat="server" Height="24px" Style="margin-left: 0px">
     <asp:ListItem>Select One</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem>Bug</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem>Enhancement</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem>Tasks</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem>New Feature</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Please help me how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also make it disabled in code behind on page load event

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IssueList.Items[0].Attributes["disabled"] = "disabled";
}
```

also make your first item selected

```
                   <asp:DropDownList ID="IssueList" runat="server" Height="24px" Style="margin-left: 0px">
                         <asp:ListItem Selected="true" Value="">Select One</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Bug</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Enhancement</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Tasks</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>New Feature</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: its working but when I put this code required field validator for dropdownlist not works even when I not selected any value yet

Comment: Still same issue

Comment: @RamiFar May i see your Validator definition?

Comment: `<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please Select one" Text="*" ControlToValidate="IssueList" ForeColor="Red" InitialValue="Select One"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>`

Comment: @RamiFar Ok, remove this attribute:  InitialValue="Select One From Issue Type"

Answer (score 2):

You can add disabled attribte.try with this:

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="id">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Test" Value="value" disabled="disabled" />
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: its working. but when I run application the item showed is Bug not Select one. when I drop the list Select one is disabled exactly how I want but I want when it runs it has to show Please select not Bug.

Answer (score 1):

You can add an 'Empty' value item:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="IssueList" runat="server" Height="24px" Style="margin-left: 0px">
    <asp:ListItem Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Select One</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Bug</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Enhancement</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Tasks</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>New Feature</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Then you would check for

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(IssueList.SelectedValue))
```

Comment: where I need to put the check and what I need to add in if statement

Comment: I do not have your source code, so I can not tell where and what you need to do.

Answer (score 1):

You could use attribute as in combination of disabled and selected. may this will help to get resolve your issue.

```
<asp:ListItem Selected="True" disabled="disabled">Select One</asp:ListItem>
                   ^^^^^^^         ^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Error ***disabled*** is not valid attribute

Comment: I think this may be warning message. have you try to run your application?